# How can I have an Android tablet to dial an Android cell phone to make calls?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, hardware, tablet, accessibility

I would like to initiate a cellular call from an Android tablet.  When doing so, I want to do so without touching the phone.

Additionally, I am wondering about using the tablet as a headset with a Bluetooth headset or pairing the BT headset with the phone.

I do not want to use VOIP or require an Internet connection.

In 2009, there was a solution from Broadcom's "Widcomm" Bluetooth stack.  This is no longer available.

Motivations:
Cell phones with a nice user interface for me are expensive and with my large fingers and poor eye sight, it is difficult to accurately push the buttons and read the text.

Cell phones don't seem to last long (4 years).  I have some tablets that have been working for over 10 years.

If a specific tablet and phone are required, this is OK, I am ready to replace my phone and a new tablet would be fine.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Tablets last the same time as Smartphones. It is just a matter of hardware quality and how you handle the device. You may be better by buying a large smartphone. In 2023 smartphones have reached screen size of a small tabled (~7"). And you should consider using voice assistants ("OK Google") to avoid having to use the screen.

Comment: Robert,  Thank you for responding.  My tablets have been larger than 7".  I prefer the tablet format for the variety of uses.  While I often use voice assistants, a significant portions of my phone time I do not want to converse with the assistant.  Further, I find I must repeat prompts often.  It seems the radio is a limiting factor in the life of a phone.  I would prefer to replace a cheap phone - I think.  I have not had a cheap phone and my phones don't last.  Of course, I cannot assure that quality has anything to do with price.  I am looking to learning about how I may control my phone.

Comment: Do you use special apps that are optimized for readability (high contrast, large font)? Linking a tablet to a smartphone is not impossible but very uncommon and thus to my knowledge not supported by stock devices. If tablet and phone are linked using BLE, an app can act as BLE GATT server, so it may be possible to have an app that acts as a Bluetooth headset.

Comment: Robert,  Thank you.  That was all new to me and there are many resources for learning more.